# Adding post ID to avoid URL crashing?

Tags: security, url-design

I am creating a website, now it's time to decide how the URL for different posts should look like.

For SEO purposes, I am planing to add the post URL, like

```
example.com/post.php?v=a-very-interesting-title
```

To prevent URL crashing, I was thinking to add the post ID to the URL, like

```
example.com/post.php?v=a-very-interesting-title-32
```

What do you think about adding the post ID to the URL, any security concerns? Should I hash the ID before adding to the URL? How should I do that?

Comment: What is "url crashing" ?

Comment: assume i want to add another post which happens to have the same title as another old post

Comment: 1. What kind of posts are these? Do they have a publication date? 2. Is there a reason why you use the query component instead of the (typically more human-friendly) path component (e.g., `example.com/posts/title`)? 3. Why do you think having the ID in the URL could be problematic for security? How do you use the ID?

Comment: @unor 1-let say each post represents an sport event, like team A vs Team B, and no, there isnt any publication date but rather a start time for the event.   2- no, not sure how to make the url follow the structure you provided. 3- i dont think id is bad for security, just curious if its possible to be used in any malicious way